# What is the significance of the memory-map length when using the mmap API?

Tags: c, posix, mmap

In POSIX, you have this nice [`mmap()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) API. The documentation is not clear whether the value of `length` has an impact on memory/performance. Please advise!

```
void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags,
           int fd, off_t offset);
```

Consider a file of 10 MB where I need to map only a subset of it, like 2 MB. Also, let's assume that we never try to access memory outside the 2 MB bounds. (Doing so obviously has an impact.)

---

**Q:** Does it matter if the `length` is set to 2 or 10 MB?

Comment: Slight nitpicking: [`mmap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) is a POSIX function, not a C function.

Comment: Performance-wise, there's not a lot of difference; there's less work to do mapping 2 MiB compared to 10 MiB, but the difference probably isn't all that large.  There's no problem mapping just a subset — go for it.

Comment: Technically, since you mention POSIX and not Linux, you cannot assume lazy allocation. So 2MB mapping might be faster than 10MB. But I don't know any platform that does not implement lazy mapping anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `length` parameter tells how much contiguous space starting from `offset` should be mapped into the memory. Mapping only first 2M of a file that has length of 10M shouldn't have adverse performance characteristics compared to mapping 10M, other than if you *need to change the mapping later* to read the other parts.

One reason for the length parameter is to avoid accessing parts that you don't want to access even by accident. Another reason is if you've got a 6G file and on a 32-bit processor, then good luck trying to map all of that 6G into 2-4G user space.